# TFS 2013 Build - An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: One or more errors occurred

Tags: tfs

After TFS upgrade 2012.4 -> 2013.4 builds finish with status 'Partially succeded and with below error:

```
An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location.
Details: One or more errors occurred.
```

Builds are conifgured to not use drop folder - so it's not permission issue.
[image]

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Is there any more information in the detailed logs?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Event Viewer of the TFS server?

Comment: Only message under 'Diagnostics' tab is: Build <BuildName> (vstfs:///Build/Build/3276) did not provide 'logs\ActivityLog.xml'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution which resolved my problem:

1. Go to Build Definition.
2. Select Process tab.
3. Set Logging Verbosity to Diagnostic.